# jQuery adding two numeric variables together to create a new value

Tags: jquery, html, variables

I'm trying to add two variables together (two different heights) but for some odd reason even though they are both numbers, it is not adding them together and just refusing to do anything. How do I add two variables together?

**HTML**

```
<div id="imageSlider">
    <div id="imagesContainer">
        <div class="left" id="selectedImage">
            <div class="sliderImageAlign">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="imagesUp">
        <div id="imagesArrowUp"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="imagesDown">
        <div id="imagesArrowDown"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var imageHeight = $("#selectedImage").height(),
        containerHeight = $("#imagesContainer").height(),
        containerPos = $("#imagesContainer").position();

    $("#tellMeHeight").text(containerHeight / imageHeight);

    $("#imagesDown").click(function(){
        var containerNewPos = parseInt(containerPos + imageHeight);

        $("#imagesContainer").css({
            top: containerNewPos + 'px'
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You should read about the methods you're using before you use them. `.position()` returns an object: http://api.jquery.com/position/ . So you can't exactly add something to it...

Comment: i'm storing the value of the position in the variable though?

Comment: BTW, to get an image's height, you have to be sure the image is loaded

Comment: `containerPos` contains the result of calling `position()`, so it is storing an object. If you want to do a calculation with it, use `containerPos.left` or `containerPos.top` to get the specific property

Comment: @roasted that won't be an issue, i measure the container for the image not the actual image because if i did it by the images height it would leave the slider being out of line. And oh i see now! I was trying to add to top and left (which isn't possible), easy enough mistake to make!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.position` return's an object , you can call `.top` or `.left` on it

```
 containerPos = $("#imagesContainer").position().top;
```